# Change Email and password + New Account

Tags: pokemon-go

I was just wondering if you could help me. 
I want to give my account to my niece since I have put some money into it. I'm tired of playing but she loves it. 
How can I switch the Email address?? Do you know? 
Please help if you can... 
Thanks,
Dita

PS: When I tried to start with a different Email, it just asks for the password.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a trainer account you can do so on the [Pokémon website](https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login).
With google the Pokémon account is linked to that account, so you would have to give her access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is not in the scope of Pokémon Go. Accounts are managed by either Google, or Pokémon Club.